# Converting number a and b to number between c and d

Tags: c#, math

So, I have a variable that goes from 12 down to 0.
I want to convert this into a number between 5 and -5.

How do I do this?

Comment: C#
I got an answer and converted it into code:)

Comment: public float mathHelp(float value, float newMax, float newMin, float oldMax, float oldMin) {
  return ((((value - oldMin) / (oldMax - oldMin)) * (newMax - newMin)) + newMin);
 }

Comment: In the future, specify more requirements/constraints for your problem. A simple `return 0;` satisfies your question as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Linear Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

`new_value = (((old_value - old_min) / (old_max - old_min)) * (new_max - new_min)) + new_min`

Comment: C#:
public float tmp(float value, float newMax, float newMin, float oldMin, float oldMax) {
  return ((((value - oldMin) / (oldMax - oldMin)) * (newMax - newMin)) + newMin);
 }

Answer (score 0):

subtract 6, divide by 6 and multiply by 5.

```
y = (x-6) * 5 / 6
```

keep in mind that this question don't belong to StackOverflow, it should be posted at [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sorry, fixing that to next time...

Answer (score 0):

N is your number beetween MAX and 0 and you want a simmetrical output between X and -X

MAX=12
X=5

output = (N - (MAX/2)) * (X/(MAX/2))